# Access denied when trying to add contact in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have added the permission for contacts. Please refer the screenshot below for reference,

[image]

Please refer to the below code and give suggestions.

```
    public function createContact()
        {
            $client = new Client();        
    
            $response = $client->post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessTokenBasedOnUser(),
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ],
                'json' => [
                    'givenName' => 'Shankari',
                    'surname' => 'S',
                    'emailAddresses' => [
                        [
                            'address' => 'shankari@outlook.com',
                            'name' => 'Shankari S'
                        ]                    
                    ],
                    'businessPhones' => [
                        '+91 7894XXXXXX', '+91 963YYYY456'
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
    
            if ($response->getStatusCode() == 201) {
                $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
                
                return "Contact created";
            } else {
                return "Failed to create the contact. HTTP Status Code: " . $response->getStatusCode();
            }
        }
```

I ran below authorization url for getting code,

```
    URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
    Input:
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'response_mode' => 'query',
    'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'state' => '12345',
```

I generated access token using authorization code flow.

```
    URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
    Input:
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access',
    'code' => $code,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
```

With the access token, I will add it in the Authorization Header as a bearer token.

Please let me know the fixes based on this.

**UPDATE**

Please refer below screenshot, working fine in Graph Explorer.

[image]

**SCOPE**

Scope for Personal Account
[image]

Scope for Azure Account[image]

Comment: Could you include what authentication flow you used to generate bearer token? authorization code flow or client credentials flow?

Comment: I have mentioned in Question section. Please check the same.

Comment: Could you run the same query in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and confirm whether it's working in it or not?

Comment: While signing in what account are you using? local Azure AD account or personal Microsoft accounts like Outlook?

Comment: Yes, it is working in Graph Explorer (included in question section). Initially tested with a personal account, it is not working. Subsequently attempted with a local Azure AD account, even though it is not working. But checked in Graph Explorer for Azure AD Account, it is working.

Comment: I am just working on that. When trying to add the access token in jwt.ms, it is not decoding it. 
But when try to sign in I could not find the scope for Contacts.ReadWrite for the specified Personal account and Azure Ad Account.
Please refer the question section for scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255979/discussion-between-sridevi-and-shankari).

Answer (score 2):

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Initially, I generated bearer token with **`/.default`** scope and got **same error** as you when I used it to create contact like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts
Authorization: Bearer <token>

{
  "givenName": "Sri",
  "surname": "Outlook",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "address": "sridevi.macxxxx@outlook.com",
      "name": "Sri Outlook"
    }
  ],
  "businessPhones": [
    "+91 90148xxxx9"
  ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you need to **accept** the consent for permissions before using **`/.default`** as scope with personal Outlook account.
>
> To **resolve** the error, use https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.ReadWrite as **scope** value while generating **`code`** and bearer token.

I ran below **authorization request** in browser changing scope, logging with personal Outlook account and got **consent screen** as below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=appId
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_type=code  
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.ReadWrite
&state=12345
```

[image]

After accepting the consent, I got **`code`** value in address bar like this:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow via Postman with below parameters:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.ReadWrite offline_access
code:<paste_code_from_above_step>
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to create contact with below json, I got **response** like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts
Authorization: Bearer <token>

{
  "givenName": "Sri",
  "surname": "Outlook",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "address": "sridevi.macxxxx@outlook.com",
      "name": "Sri Outlook"
    }
  ],
  "businessPhones": [
    "+91 90148xxxx9"
  ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in user's contact where new **contact** created successfully as below:

[image]